# How do I get more clothing in Hyrule Warriors: Age of Calamity?

Tags: hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity

How do I get more clothing in Hyrule Warriors: Age of Calamity?

I have finished the Hyrule Warriors: Age of Calamity storyline, and I'm wondering how to get more clothing for Zelda, other than her research outfit, goddess outfit, and winter clothes. Can somebody tell me if there are any more clothes for the champions, other than their champion's outfit and casual outfit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing through multiple sources, including [the IGN Wiki](https://www.ign.com/wikis/hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity/List_of_Attire_and_Unlockable_Outfits#Revali.27s_Outfits_and_Attire), [the Zelda Wiki](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Attire#), an article at [screenrant.com](https://screenrant.com/unlock-every-costume-hyrule-warriors-calamity/) and [a walkthrough at gamewith.net](https://gamewith.net/hyrule-warriors-age-of-calamity/article/show/21945), it does not look like Zelda has any further costumes. In fact, most of the unlocked clothing options are specific to Link. All other champions only have a single piece of unlockable clothing, apart from Zelda, who has two.

---

[image]

You can find all available attire pieces, below, along with their respective unlock conditions.

### Link (Chest)

- **[A1] Champion's Tunic:** Complete the *"The Road Home, Besieged"* scenario
- **[A2] Hylian Tunic:** Complete the *"Freeing Korok Forest"* scenario.
- **[A3] Warm Doublet:** Complete the *"The King's Secret Technique"* quest.
- **[A4] Snowquill Tunic:** Complete the *"The White Bird of Talonto Peak"* quest.
- **[A5] Desert Voe Spaulder:** Complete the *"Urbosa, the Gerudo Chief"* scenario.
- **[A6] Gerudo Top:** Complete the *"Miss Vai Battle Pageant"* challenge.
- **[A7] Rubber Armor:** Complete the *"The So-Called Knight"* challenge.
- **[A8] Flamebreaker Armor:** Complete the *"Daruk, the Goron Hero"* scenario.
- **[A9] Zora Armor:** Complete the *"Heart's Escort"* challenge.
- **[A10] Stealth Chest Guard:** Complete the *"Village Training Secrets"* quest.
- **[A11] Climbing Gear:** Complete the *"The Hope of Necluda"* quest.
- **[B1] Barbarian Armor:** Complete the *"Coliseum: Expert"* challenge.
- **[B2] Radiant Shirt:** Complete the *"Deep Woods, Deep Shadow"* challenge.
- **[B3] Sand Boots:** Complete the *"Surveying the Desert Ruins"* quest.
- **[B4] Dark Tunic:** Complete the *"Unnatural Disaster"* challenge.
- **[B5] Tunic of the Wild:** Complete the *"Hyrule's Greatest Warrior"* challenge.
- **[B6] Hyrule Warrior's Tunic:** Complete the *"The Hope of All Hyrule"* quest.
- **[B7] Royal Guard Uniform:** Complete the *"King Rhoam's Training"* challenge.

### Link (Head)

- **[B8] Hylian Hood:** Complete the *"Freeing Korok Forest"* scenario.
- **[B9] Amber Earrings:** Complete the *"Not a Light Meal"* quest.
- **[B10] Ruby Circlet:** Complete the *"The Hope of Eldin"* quest.
- **[B11] Snowquill Headdress:** Complete the *"Fierce Gale of the Riot"* challenge.
- **[C1] Sapphire Circlet:** Complete the *"The Hope of Lanayru"* quest.
- **[C2] Desert Voe Headband:** Complete the *" Leave None Behind"* challenge.
- **[C3] Gerudo Veil:** Complete the *"Miss Vai Battle Pageant"* challenge.
- **[C4] Topaz Earrings:** Complete the *"Time for an Upgrade"* quest.
- **[C5] Rubber Helm:** Complete the *"Shocking Design Choices"* quest.
- **[C6] Flamebreaker Helm:** Complete the *"Fighting Fire With…"* quest.
- **[C7] Opal Earrings:** Complete the *"The Hope of Central Hyrule"* quest.
- **[C8] Zora Helm:** Complete the *"Mipha, the Zora Princess"* scenario.
- **[C9] Stealth Mask:** Complete the *"A Thief in our Midst"* quest.
- **[C10] Thunder Helm:** Complete the *"The Hope of Gerudo"* quest.
- **[C11] Climber's Bandanna:** Complete the *"Mountain Rescue"* challenge.
- **[D1] Barbarian Helm:** Complete the *"Anti-Elemental Training"* challenge.
- **[D2] Radiant Mask:** Complete the *"Deep Woods, Deep Shadow"* challenge.
- **[D3] Diamond Circlet:** Complete the *"Hunting for Gemstones"* challenge.
- **[D4] Bokoblin Mask:** Complete the *"A Rumor about Skull Lake"* quest.
- **[D5] Moblin Mask:** Complete the *"Cold Desert Nights"* quest.
- **[D6] Lizalfos Mask:** Complete the *"Visiting a Special Shop"* quest.
- **[D7] Lynel Mask:** Complete the *"Mystery Meal for the Merchant"* quest.
- **[D8] Dark Hood:** Complete the *"Questionable Escort Mission"* quest.
- **[D9] Cap of the Wild:** Complete the *"Hyrule's Greatest Warrior"* challenge.
- **[D10] Hyrule Warrior's Cap:** Complete the *"The Hope of All Hyrule"* quest.
- **[D11] Royal Guard Cap:** Complete the *"King Rhoam's Training"* challenge.

### Link (Legs)

- **[E1] Hylian Trousers:** Complete the *"Freeing Korok Forest"* scenario.
- **[E2] Snowquill Trousers:** Complete the *"Revali, the Rito Warrior"* scenario.
- **[E3] Desert Voe Trousers:** Complete the *"the Colorful Kara Kara Bazaar"* quest.
- **[E4] Gerudo Sirwal:** Complete the *"Miss Vai Battle Pageant"* challenge.
- **[E5] Rubber Tights:** Complete the *"The Hope of Faron"* quest.
- **[E6] Flamebreaker Boots:** Complete the *"the Tough Bulwark of the Gorons"* quest.
- **[E7] Zora Greaves:** Complete the *"the Armor for Whom?"* quest.
- **[E8] Stealth Tights:** Complete the *"The Hope of Akkala"* quest.
- **[E9] Climbing Boots:** Complete the *"Perils of Mount Hylia"* quest.
- **[E10] Barbarian Leg Wraps:** Complete the *"Hair-Width Trial: Expert+"* challenge.
- **[E11] Radiant Tights:** Complete the *"Deep Woods, Deep Shadow"* challenge.
- **[F1] Snow Boots:** Complete the *"The Hope of Hebra"* quest.
- **[F2] Dark Trousers:** Complete the *"Fire Hazards"* challenge.
- **[F3] Trousers of the Wild:** Complete the *"Hyrule's Greatest Warrior"* challenge.
- **[F4] Hyrule Warrior's Trousers:** Complete the *"The Hope of All Hyrule"* quest.
- **[F5] Royal Guard Boots:** Complete the *"King Rhoam's Training"* challenge.

### Other Characters

- **[F6] Zelda's Ceremonial Robes:** Complete the *"The Future of Hyrule"* scenario.
- **[F7] Zelda's Winter Clothes:** Complete the *"The Future of Hyrule"* scenario.
- **[F8] Mipha's Champion Garb:** Complete the *"The Future of Hyrule"* scenario.
- **[F9] Daruk's Champion Garb:** Complete the *"The Future of Hyrule"* scenario.
- **[F10] Revali's Champion Garb:** Complete the *"The Future of Hyrule"* scenario.
- **[F11] Urbosa's Champion Garb:** Complete the *"The Future of Hyrule"* scenario.

Comment: thank you so much it was really helpful and sorry I did not know about the 1 question thing

Comment: @animeandkpopgirl if an answer helps you, you can tick the green tick icon at the top left of the answer to accept it. This will help others with the same questions, in the future.